# Get error message on isUnique attribute MVC

Tags: unique-constraint, asp.net-mvc-5.2, validationmessage

I have a model property like below,

```
[Index("CourseCodeIndex", IsUnique = true)]
[MaxLength(15)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and if I use invalid data it works well but returns no error message. Is there any way to show a message on (view, like other required like messages)

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an instance of your context file

```
private datbaseContext db = new databaseContext();
```

add the code below to your controller action method

```
db.table.Add(model);
                var user = db.table.Where(u => u.Name == model.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", model.Name + " Already Exists");
                }
                else
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "model");    
                }
```

And the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` from your view will attach the error message

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show the error message, you need to declare it like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Compiletime error required")]
```

Also, try this.

```
 [Unique(ErrorMessage = "This already exist !!")]
```